# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed Issue migrating to SpringBoot 2

Tags: spring-boot, illegalstateexception

I am recently trying to migrate a legacy Java based application to Spring boot 2, I have included all the Spring based dependencies but I am getting below error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:323)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)

Please let me know if we have a clue on the issue

Comment: This exception means that you are trying to process a response twice. Hard to guess where, without seeing the code. It can happen for instance when you write to a response (i.e. this happens automatically if you return anything in your controller, can also happen in security layer) and second time manually using for instance `requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);` in the same controller or in some other place like an interceptor, filter, etc.

Comment: but my concern is why we were not seeing the issue in weblogic but when we migrate to Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat, if you could advise if there is some behavior of tomcat we need to take care of

Comment: You can run Spring Boot app on whatever server you want, either Weblogic or Tomcat (embedded or standalone). In case of Web logic, please have in mind that this is a JEE server and Tomcat is just a web server (so you may be missing support for some JEE components out of the box) - but this would lead to other issues than you report. Please share your Spring Boot configuration (including @Configuration classes). Without this, it is hard to help you.